# ul li css not working properly

Tags: html, css

Got a strange issue:

In my .cshtml I have a second thing:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test2
        <ul>
            <li>Test3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test4
        <ul>
            <li>Test5</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Test6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which supposed to work like this:

```
Test
Test2
     Test3
Test4
     Test5
     Test6
```

**BUT** instead of it, it works this way:

```
Test
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Test6
```

The only thing I have in css for this is `list-style: none;`
Also main `<ul>` is placed inside of `<div>` which have `text-align: left;` (without it, all items are centered).

I am a newbie speaking of css so, I can't get, what I am missing.

**EDIT:**
Forgot one thing. This works fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: It is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/or8umusk/

Comment: I know that its works fine in jsfiddle. Thats the problem. Because of this I can't detect what is wrong.

Comment: the property `list-style:none` makes it align in same line. if you remove this style than it will work fine

Comment: Check your css files there must be conflict, or to avoid this use some class for / before starting ul... https://jsfiddle.net/8608vaoy/1/ works fine

Comment: If you have `padding` or `margin` remove it from CSS. Like `padding:0px;` or `margin:0px;`

Comment: **The OP is using `<li>` for closing tags too!!!**

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Check my fiddle. You are using `<li>` for closing tags too!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just reset all your styles and give `</li>`. You are using `<li>` only for opening and closing it:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test2
    <ul>
      <li>Test3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Test4
    <ul>
      <li>Test5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Test6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Your Mistake**

```
<ul>
    <li>Test<li> <!-- Should be </li> not <li> -->
    <li>Test2
        <ul>
            <li>Test3</li>
        </ul>
    <li><!-- Should be </li> not <li> -->
    <li>Test4
        <ul>
            <li>Test5</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Test6</li>
        </ul>
    <li><!-- Should be </li> not <li> -->
</ul>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just check this out...

**OR**

Provide the **CSS** you have used..

```css
div {
  text-align: left;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test2
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test4
      <ul>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>Test6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with is that you should wrap your un-ordered list with div tag that has a class name. **Ex.** `<div class="test"></div>`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test2
            <ul>
                <li>Test3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test4
            <ul>
                <li>Test5</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>Test6</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left; 
}
```

Comment: This works just the way you want it. I don't understand what you are trying to figure out here?

Comment: Read the question properly please.

Comment: I did. This did work PERFECTLY on JsFiddle. Also, do you have your files named properly? Double check because the issue could be from the IDE you're using.

Comment: Boss, I am using my mind. See if this is valid or not. If this is validated I will give you `100 £` seriously.

Comment: Seriously, I don't wanna lose my rep. StackOverflow is filled with such low quality posts now.

Comment: @PraveenKumar do you have this on a website? Show me a result of what appears on the screen in whatever that you're using.

Comment: Bro, what's the closing tag of `<li>`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be your issue.

- `padding:0px;`
- `margin:0px;`

```css
ul li ul
{
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test2
        <ul>
            <li>Test3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test4
        <ul>
            <li>Test5</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Test6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**ANSWER**

> **Note :** So remove padding property from your `ul` CSS.

```css
ul li ul
{
   /* padding:0px; REMOVE IT If It's 0PX' */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test2
        <ul>
            <li>Test3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test4
        <ul>
            <li>Test5</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Test6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seriously, I don't wanna lose my rep. StackOverflow is filled with such low quality posts now.

Comment: actually i didn't saw that, i never thought someone would make such mistake. So just copy pasted the HTML code.

Comment: It's not that i rewrote it. My main focus was to point that `padding` or `margin` could be the reason. Anyways thanks updating the answer.